# Display the last known location with onConnected()

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to get to last known Location with the aid of `GoogleApiClient` I followed the guide in the link:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

I have tested my code below also the `buildGoogleApiClient()` is being invoked but not the `onConnected()`. Therefor, the last known Location is not being displayed.

The Google map is being displayed.

How can I get the last known Location with this Approach?

**Map activity:**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        buildGoogleApiClient();
}

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
         System.out.println("ABC buildGoogleApiClient map was invoked: ");
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
             double lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
             double lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();

            if(myLocatMarker != null){
                myLocatMarker.remove();
            }
             LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
             MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions().title("my location")
                     .position(ll)
                     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.myloc));
             System.out.println("ABC onConnected map: "+ lat + " ; " + lng);
             myLocatMarker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);                

        }

    }
}
```

**Edit map activity:**

public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener{
        GoogleMap map;
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        Location mLastLocation;
        Marker myLocatMarker;

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        buildGoogleApiClient();

}
    @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap arg0) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect(); 
    System.out.println("ABC onMapReady");
}
private boolean initMap() {
    if (map == null) {
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map = mapFrag.getMap();
    }
    return (map != null);
}
    @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);      
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<ItemDTO> list = (ArrayList<ItemDTO>) intent
            .getSerializableExtra("list_data");
    for (ItemDTO itemDTO : list) {
        int id = itemDTO.getBusId();
        double latitude = itemDTO.getLatitude();
        double longitude = itemDTO.getLongitude();
        int route1 = itemDTO.getRoute();
        String route = Integer.toString(route1);
        String direction = itemDTO.getDirection();
        String route_dirc = route + ", " + direction;

        if (initMap()) {
            gotoLocation(id, latitude, longitude, route_dirc);                                              

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Map not avialable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }
}

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
         System.out.println("ABC buildGoogleApiClient map was invoked: ");
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
             double lng = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
             double lat = mLastLocation.getLatitude();

            if(myLocatMarker != null){
                myLocatMarker.remove();
            }
             LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
             MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions().title("my location")
                     .position(ll)
                     .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.myloc));
             System.out.println("ABC onConnected map: "+ lat + " ; " + lng);
             myLocatMarker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);                

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251077/accesing-current-location-of-users-in-android-app/32251206#32251206

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you call buildGoogleApiClient() you need to call mGoogleApiClient.connect().  This should make onConnected() get called.

Comment: Your answer works for me but why did not they but it in the tutorial ;).

Comment: but when I click the back button I am getting `'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference`!

Comment: `Map.onConnected(Map.java:494)`

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code?  ** Hang on I am multitasking- which is  never a good thing.  Let me think about this for a minute.

Comment: I bet it has something to do with Activity Lifecycle.  I'm thinking when you go to you new activity onPause() is called and when you hit the back button onResume() should be called.  Try to reinitialize myLocatMarker, I'm  not sure if this will fix it as I am not sitting in front of your computer, but I check back to look at what you find.

Comment: So I have added more code I hope it helps. I have tried to call  `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` inside `onReadyMap()` but this method is not being invoked in my case. I ma calling `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);` in the `onCraete()`.